# Lightness of touch

Tags: meaning-in-context

"His style is characterized by a lightness of touch and attention to detail."
 Hi. In this sentence which is about a sculptor, what is meant by "a lightness of touch"? Does it make sense regarding the next phrase "attention to detail"?  Isn't it a paradox as "lightness of touch" means "taking easy" and "attention to detail" needs taking something seriously?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I would understand it to mean **light** in this sense: *Moving easily and quickly; nimble* Think *deft*.

Answer (score 5):

This is an aesthetic judgement, contrasted with something done with a *heavy hand*.

It probably implies the resulting sculpture is notable for subtle details rather than strong or highly pronounced features.

Like any aesthetic judgement, use of this term is a matter of opinion and one person might see a sculpture as having been executed with a light touch, while another might think the same work was done with a heavy hand.

Comment: Strangely, I understand it more literally. One would want to chisel lightly (that is, with less force) in order to make out fine details, and heavily (that is, with more force) in order to hew large hunks of rock. The light hand is better for detail, a heavy hand for large features.

Answer (score 0):

For an artist I would interpret "lightness of touch" to imply that the artist was given to subtle effects.  Eg, careful use of color shading rather than bright, bold colors, and careful attention to, say, the contours of a sculpture face, vs angular chin and nose.

Answer (score 0):

To me, a sculptor known as having a LIGHT TOUCH means, that his/her art won't include hard corners, nor straight lines. Instead we'll see arcs of the largest circles, down through arcs from circles that have a smaller radius than a U.S. Dime. I submit that an excellent sculpture of a nude person would be created in such a style. No aspect of such a style prevents fine detail. E.G. Michelangelo's work - DAVID